# Gravity Forms: How to add PHP function to confirmation conditional shortcode?

Tags: php, functions, shortcode, plugin-gravity-forms

In Gravity Forms, I have a confirmation set up with various conditional shortcodes. Example:

```
[gravityforms action="conditional" merge_tag="{:3:value}" condition="contains" value="E"]*** GET A CATEGORY ***[/gravityforms]
```

Additionally, I have a PHP function that gets all posts by category, and I would like to use this function inside the conditional shortcode. I'm not figuring out a way to do this, so any help would be appreciated.

My function: `useful_tools_list(array( 'type' => 'documents', desc => 'true' ))`

I also made it into a shortcode: `[useful-tools type="documents" desc="true"]`

I tried using `<?php ?>`, but I realized I can't embed PHP into the editor. The conditional shortcode doesn't support nesting other shortcodes inside of it, so that doesn't work.

I'm wondering if there is a way to manipulate the GF conditional shortcode to allow nesting? Or another way of calling the function that I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of use shortcode in your confirmation, you can use [the filter hook "gform_confirmation"](https://docs.gravityforms.com/gform_confirmation/) for manage your confirmation. After, you'll be able to use your shortcode [useful-tools] with [do_shortcode()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_shortcode/) with your confirmation.

Sorry if I misunderstood your problem!

Comment: That is a possibility. Thank you for this. I would rather not have to create an entire confirmation out of PHP only because I have coworkers that aren't familiar with PHP and would like to make changes to the confirmation from the GF editor if possible. I suppose if all else fails, this will be the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a solution that will work without having to build out an entire confirmation via PHP. This won't work for everyone's situation, but since I did build out my own function/shortcode, it works for me.

I added the conditional logic to my shortcode and removed the GF shortcode altogether. To do so, I added merge_tag and value parameters like so:

```
[useful-tools type="documents" desc="true" merge_tag="{:3:value}" value="B"]
```

For those that want to see my shortcode, I'm including it here. It is set up to list all custom post types matching a custom taxonomy. It can also be used to list them outside of GF by removing the parameters.

```
function useful_tools_list($atts){
    $atts = shortcode_atts(
        array(
            'type'  => '',
            'desc'  => '',
            'ul'    => '',
            'li'    => '',
            'merge_tag' => '',
            'value' => '',
         ), 
        $atts
    );
    
    $results = '';
    if (($atts['merge_tag']) && (!preg_match('/\b'.$atts['value'].'\b/', $atts['merge_tag']))) {
        $results .= '';
    } else {
        $all_terms = get_terms('types');

        foreach($all_terms as $term) {
            wp_reset_query();
            if (($atts['type']) && ($atts['type'] != "")) {
                $args = array('post_type' => 'useful-tools',
                    'tax_query' => array(
                        array(
                            'taxonomy' => 'types',
                            'field' => 'slug',
                            'terms' => $term->slug,
                        ),
                    ),
                    'types' => $atts['type'],
                 );
            } else {
                $args = array('post_type' => 'useful-tools',
                    'tax_query' => array(
                        array(
                            'taxonomy' => 'types',
                            'field' => 'slug',
                            'terms' => $term->slug,
                        ),
                    ),
                 );
            }

            $loop = new WP_Query($args);
            if($loop->have_posts()) {
                if ((!$atts['type']) || ($atts['type'] == "")) {
                    $results .= '<h2>'.$term->name.'</h2>';
                }
                if (($atts['ul']) && ($atts['ul'] == "true")) {
                    $results .= '<ul class="tools-type-ul">';
                }
                while($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();
                $postID = get_the_ID();
                $desc = '';
                $actualDesc = get_post_meta($postID, '_post_desc', true);
                if ($atts['desc'] == 'true' && $actualDesc != '') {
                    $desc = ' - '.get_post_meta($postID, '_post_desc', true);
                }
                if (($atts['li']) && ($atts['li'] == "true")) {
                    $results .= '<li><a href="'.get_post_meta($postID, '_post_url', true).'">'.get_the_title().'</a>'.$desc.'</li>';
                } else {
                    $results .= '<a href="'.get_post_meta($postID, '_post_url', true).'">'.get_the_title().'</a>'.$desc.'<br>';
                }
                endwhile;
                if (($atts['ul']) && ($atts['ul'] == "true")) {
                    $results .= '</ul>';
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $results;
}
add_shortcode('useful-tools', 'useful_tools_list');
```